# How to insert order and orderitems in single rest call in salesforce

Tags: rest, order

How to insert order and orderitems in single rest call in salesforce?

## Add an Order to an Existing Account

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_placeorder.meta/api_placeorder/sforce_placeorder_rest_api_place_order_account.htm

## Add Order Products to an Existing Order

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_placeorder.meta/api_placeorder/sforce_placeorder_rest_api_add_orderprod.htm

I want to achieve the above two using a single rest call..that is I wish to add order and orderitems at the same time .Any help would be highly helpful.Thanks.

Comment: From which system you are calling this API? You can create a custom REST API to insert both order and orderlineitem in salesforce and pass json data as parent child.

Comment: Thanks for the information...I am newbie in salesforce can you provide an example for the same.And also can it be achieved by standard REST API in any way ?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using [Salesforce composite API.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm)  . Composite api allows you to provide complex JSON for inserting/updating/deleting/searching different sobjects in the form of subrequests.

It also supports referenceId's in subrequests.

> In a subrequest’s body, you specify a reference ID that maps to the
>   subrequest’s response. You can then refer to the ID in the url or body
>   fields of later subrequests by using a JavaScript-like reference
>   notation.

which mean you can insert parent and child in same call using `refrenceId`

consider the documented example of inserting Parent Account and child contact in same call.

```
{
"compositeRequest" : [{
  "method" : "POST",
  "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account",
  "referenceId" : "refAccount",
  "body" : { "Name" : "Sample Account" }
  },{
  "method" : "POST",
  "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact",
  "referenceId" : "refContact",
  "body" : { 
    "LastName" : "Sample Contact",
    "AccountId" : "@{refAccount.id}"
    }
  }]
}
```

You can do same to create order, orderline item in same call